# Xcode 6 how to enable storyboard zoom?

Tags: zooming, uistoryboard, xcode6

I've updated to Xcode 6 beta 3 and see that the **[+ = -] buttons** in the storyboard corner are gone. Is there a way for me to zoom in and out on view controllers within a storyboard in Xcode 6?

Comment: Wy have they removed it? I used it all of the time and I am really struggling now.

Comment: After day after, Apple makes harder to use this Xcode really. That simple process should be easy, i shouldn't press ⇧ ⌥ ⌘ { to zoom. ARGH APPLE!

Comment: You can always change the shortcut to something more convenient.

Comment: @gaurav: You shouldn't have to change the shortcuts, though. The default should be something reasonable. Customizing shortcuts should be for if someone has a really weirdly specific workflow they need, or if they're used to using a different program which had similar functionality. This keyboard shortcut seems like they came up with it by just picking 4 (why 4‽) random keys.

Comment: **Command+Alt+Shift+{** for zoom out OR **Command+Alt+Shift+}** for zoom in AND **Command+Alt+Shift+|** for 100%.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can zoom the storyboard by double-click canvas or using top-menu(Editor > Canvas > Zoom).

Alternatively: Right click blank space on canvas and choose zoom level (allows to zoom out further than double click)

[image]

Comment: ...or right click on any white space to bring up the same zoom menu quickly.

Comment: @flinth, zoom in/out is not for XIBs. It's only for storyboards.

Comment: @iAmGroot I already know that, but I think this is nice feature for iPad xib files, especially if you work at the MacBook :)

Comment: @flinth yes it could be.

Comment: **Command+Alt+Shift+{** for zoom out OR **Command+Alt+Shift+}** for zoom in AND **Command+Alt+Shift+|** for 100%.

Comment: In XCode 7, you can zoom in and out using `⌘`+`+`  and `⌘`+`-`

Comment: That does not work for Mac OS app storyboards, only for iOS storyboards.

Comment: @Kenny Any idea why?

Answer (score 27):

If you have a magic trackpad (external or embedded in the macbook) you can also pinch to zoom... It sounds quite obvious, but I've just discovered it.

Comment: Yes it worked, but I've discovered it not before than a month ago after a video tutorial for unified storyboards I've watched. Amazing, but my Magic Mouse feels betrayed :)

Comment: Since XCode 6.1 this pinch zoom is very slow.

Comment: @Prine - since XCode6.1, almost everything seems very slow.

Comment: This is so dumb.  You can use the trackpad to zoom to any level.. but then it'll snap to, say 100% or 50%.  And STILL you can't select items on the Storyboard unless you're at 100%.  I'm sorry.. what year is this again ?

Comment: You're right. But I think it's worth to be pointed out that, while it's true that you can't SELECT items while zoomed out, you're still allowed to create segues and outlets from subviews of any view controller without zooming in.

Answer (score 21):

double cick is best
for zooming IN and OUT... just do a DOUBLE CLICK in the story board in Xcode 6

Comment: double click only changes between two zoom levels, while there are 4 available. Sometimes double click is not enough.

Answer (score 14):

These keyboard shortcuts are working for me:

**Zoom out:**

⇧ ⌥ ⌘ {

**Zoom in:**

⇧ ⌥ ⌘ }

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hm, using the shift key seems to be required because the curly braces are the upper case option for that key, but because of MacOS' use of the shift key as a modifier to slow down animations, it seems to force the zoom to go in slow motion. Anyone have success with this without the shift key?  (screenshot of latest xcode shows no shift character http://i.imgur.com/riIhsvg.png

Comment: great shortcut, how to press all those keys together?

Comment: press 'shift + option + command + {' OR 'shift + option + command }' Sometimes the option key is also referred to as 'alt'

Comment: to fix the slow zoom, just rebind your keybindings for canvas zoom.  They default to `shift+option+command+[` and since the shift modifier slows the animations down, changing it to something like `command+[` will resolve the issue (note you may have keybinding conflicts you have to fix).  The exact name of the keybinding is Zoom -> Zoom In (Editor Menu for Interface Builder).

Answer (score 7):

In order to zoom in or zoom out **using a mouse** just hold `alt` (⌥) and scroll.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 7, the shortcuts have changed to the following:

- **Zooming out   :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
- **Zooming In    :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
- **Normal (100%) :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl (^)</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Right click on the empty area of your storyboard, a popup menu will be shown like below:

[image: Menu]

You can use this popup to zoom in/out the storyboard (or check the keyboard shortcuts shown in that).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to RIGHT CLICK on the canvas, and zooming options will pop up

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode7.0 Beta zooming the View Controller window requires
shortcut keys: command + '+' and command + '-'

You can also right click in the white space surrounding the view-controller (diagram) to get zoom menu options in a pop-up (Note: The Xcode App must have focus for this to work or you will NOT get the zoom pop-up).