# Zoom in Universal Storyboard Preview (XCode 6)

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, xcode6

I know how to zoom in and out in the universal storyboard, but how can i do it in the storyboard preview?  I can see like a fourth of the iPad renderer only, none the less multiple devices at once.

Comment: Please refer this link to helps you...<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634867/xcode-6-how-to-enable-storyboard-zoom>

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found out the answer is you double click in the white space. Hope this helps someone out

Comment: Only two settings? In and out?

Comment: @IanWarburton I wrote this about 3 years ago so things might have changed.  Id try the pinch gesture with your cursor in the whitespace as well on the trackpad.  Or shift(maybe cmd?) + mouse scroll to get more control